# Custom control drawn shrunk at runtime but not in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I created a very simple user control in VS 2013.  My entire process was: Add -> New -> User Control, set its Size property to `16, 16` , and to override `OnPaint()` to contain the following:

```
VisualStyleRenderer treeClose = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Closed);
treeClose.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
```

I then added the control to the main form of my project.  In the Design View it is drawn correctly on the form, but at runtime it appears to be shrunk down to ~12x12 with a 16x16 background:

[image: screenshot comparison]

I tried adding it on a new blank form in a new project just to check, and the behavior was the same.  I don't have any non-default scaling or style settings in Windows (8.1) or anything like that either.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try this: In the Control Panel, change the DPI setting to 100%. You can find this under Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Display > Change the size of all items

Comment: @Abhishek At 100% it was drawn properly at runtime and the sizes matched (visually looking like the smaller of the two above) ... strange that 125% is the default.  Even more confusing is that I have changed it back to 125%, and it's now drawn properly at runtime (so both look like the bigger one above).  Very weird.

Comment: I came across such a problem earlier. Maximum I could do anything was to set the DPI to 100 based on some Google search. After that I couldn't pursue it..
After you change the dpi back to 125% you'll have to logout and log in for changes to take effect.